# How to iterate over an array of stdObject elements in PHP?

Tags: php, object, foreach, stdclass

This is the print_r() version of a data structure that I need to access via a foreach loop:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [DetailedResponse] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                ( ...
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                ( 
...
```

Now, how do I iterate though these objects?

I can sense that I should be doing something like this:

```
$object->DetailedResponse[0];
$object->DetailedResponse[1];
```

But how do I put it in a foreach type loop!!

Comment: How can we answer this if you're not showing what you are `var_export()` ing?

Comment: this *is* what is var_exported!

Comment: Pekka, it *is* `var_export()`-ed. Look in the [PHP Manual](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), example #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like there are multiple objects in that obj.. you might need to do more foreach loops..
this code should get you the first sessionId in that obj.

```
foreach ($detailedresponses as $detailedresponse) {
    foreach ($detailedresponseas as $response) {
        echo $response->sessionId;

    }
}
```

run this code to see the obj in a clearer way:
`echo '<pre>'; print_r($detailsresponses); exit;`

replace '$detailedresponses' with your correct variable name and post it back here, it should make things easier to read.

**EDIT**
check out this URL, I put my test data in there:
http://pastie.org/1130373

I recreated the object you're getting and put comments in there so you can understand what's happening :)

AND, you can get the properties like this:

```
echo $object->DetailedResponse[0]->sessionId;
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delay - this worked perfectly! I didnt like using the first foreach, but hey, its working!

Answer (score 0):

very simple. you have a so called standard-object of php.
it's accessable like any other object in php by the `$object->property` syntax

so you can iterate over it this way:
`foreach($object as $property)`, or `foreach($object as $prop_name => $prop_val)`
where you can access the properties by `$object->$prop_name`.

Comment: Hi helle - could you have a look at the specifix of the issue i'm facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a class, for re-using it later, you'd better to use [`serialize`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: This comment gives a reason for using serialize/unserialize over var_export: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php#94333

Answer (score 0):

Got a good solution to this - had a stdClass that contained other stdClases and arrays

```
function cleanEveryElement($someStdClass) {
    foreach ($someStdClass as &$property) {        
        if ($property instanceof stdClass || is_array($property)) {
            $property = cleanEveryElement($property);
        }
    else {
        // Perform some function on each element, eg:
        $property = trim($property);
        }
    }
return $someStdClass;
}
```